# Select multiple values in combobox in linked SharePoint table

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, combobox

I have a linked table to SharePoint in Access and in this table (not UserForm) I have combobox with numbers of sharepoint ID users.

[image]

How I can select multiple values in this combobox using VBA ?

Comment: Added image from comment.  Changed title to reflect combobox in linked SharePoint table.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by 'select multiple values'.

Combobox is a form control. In a table there is a field with dropdown list (lookup settings).

VBA cannot directly reference table field dropdown list. Has to be a form with combobox.

If you have a multi-column combobox and want to pull data from several columns of one row then, with table as RecordSource for a form, pull combobox data by referencing column index. Index begins with 0. Like:

Me.combobox.Column(0)

If you want to select multiple items (rows) then sounds like you want a multi-value field and multi-select combobox/dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select multiple records in a ComboBox, but you can certainly do this using a ListBox.  Here is some sample code to experiment with.

The following code uses a For...Next loop to gather all the selections from the lstOffice list box and join them together, separated by commas, into a text string. The text string is stored in a variable called strOffice...

```
For Each varItem In Me.lstOffice.ItemsSelected
    strOffice = strOffice & ",'" & Me.lstOffice.ItemData(varItem) _
    & "'"
Next varItem
```

The next step is to check the length of the resulting string. If its length is zero, it means that the user didn't select anything. So the next section of code takes the form of an If Statement which builds a suitable criteria string representing the users choice...

```
If Len(strOffice) = 0 Then
    strOffice = "Like '*'"
Else
    strOffice = Right(strOffice, Len(strOffice) - 1)
    strOffice = "IN(" & strOffice & ")"
End If
```

The code comes from here.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut18.htm

You can download a sample zipped copy of all this source code form the bottom of that page.